# Disable auto-start of application pool in IIS

Tags: .net, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, autostart

When I stop an application pool in IIS, it starts automatically after few minutes. I want it to be stopped until I decide to start it again manually. 
However, I cannot find any settings that would prevent auto-start of the particular application. 
Do you know if there's any way how can I do this?

[image]

Comment: just go to services.msc and change its service property - startup type to manually. I dont know which service might be running regarding **IIS** but this might work.

Comment: the particular application pool is not part of services.msc

Comment: Refer This - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677285(v=azure.10).aspx

Comment: You would have to use IIS configuration audit to see what enables the pool after you disable it. https://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/iis-7-5-how-to-enable-iis-configuration-auditing IIS itself should not do that.

Comment: well, it seems like it's not that easy to just simple disable autostart...

Answer (score 2):

Hit your windows button.
Search for "Services"
In "Services" go to "World Wide Web Publishing"
Right click it and under the "General" tab change "Startup type" to "Manual"

Answer (score 0):

Use following command to properly stop the IIS:
`net stop was /y`

and to start again:
`net start w3svc`

You can also save these commands and create a `bat` file which needs to be saved as `.bat`.

Answer (score 0):

All of these responses are assuming that there is only one app pool so your suggestion of turning of or setting the www service means that IIS will not be running.  You can have multiple site and all pools in IIS and only want to keep one of them from restating on boot.